# Use modern link select cursor icon in visual studio 2019 app

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, visual-studio

Hi I have built a windows forms application in visual studio 2019.
I have selected the hand cursor icon to show when my cursor hovers over a button.
My problem is that visual studio 2019 uses the old hand icon instead of the window 10 default new icon.
How can I get visual studio 2019 to allow me to use the desired cursor icon?

Old hand cursor icon in orange box.

[image]

New hand cursor icon in red box.
This is the cursor I want to use in my visual studio 2019 Winforms project.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this is better suited for StackOverflow than SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, but it's quite ugly.

For whatever reason, the standard cursors set in `Windows.Forms` include a pre-defined one for "Hand" instead of the one the user has selected in their settings. It might be for compatibility with older Windows versions, which didn't have such a setting, but in any case I don't think you can use that.

The next best thing would be to read the actual setting from Windows, find the path to the cursor file and use it to create a "new" cursor.

The only way I found to get that file's path was through the registry. In this case: `Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors", "Hand", null).ToString();`

The `Cursor` class does have a constructor that accepts the path of a cursor, but it seems to be quite badly implemented, according to other questions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305800/using-custom-colored-cursors-in-a-c-sharp-windows-application)). It can only handle black-and-white ones, and not animated cursors.

Using code from the question I linked above, the end result would look sort of like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static Cursor LoadCustomCursor(string path)
    {
        IntPtr hCurs = LoadCursorFromFile(path);
        if (hCurs == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Win32Exception();
        var curs = new Cursor(hCurs);
        // Note: force the cursor to own the handle so it gets released properly
        var fi = typeof(Cursor).GetField("ownHandle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        fi.SetValue(curs, true);
        return curs;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string path);

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors", "Hand", null).ToString();
        var hand = LoadCustomCursor(path);
        button1.Cursor = hand;
    }
}
```

This seems to have worked on my system, for both static and animated cursors. Of course it would be best to add some error handling.